# How to reattach thread or wait for thread completion before exiting

Tags: c++, multithreading, std, stdthread

I have an application that connects to a socket using the asio library. My main thread calls an `open()` to the socket implementation where it is then detached from the main thread to continue execution.

When `thread::detach()` is called, the thread can no longer be joined and thus the caller has no idea when the thread has completed its execution. This results, at least in my application, of an unclean shutdown. Resources aren't deallocated properly and, only sometimes, leads to a crash. Is it possible to rejoin the detached thread? I would like to try and avoid using a condition variable.

Here is my example:

```
io_socket io = new io_socket();

// The call to thread::detach() is done within io_socket::open()
io->open();

// Let some things happen...
std::this_thread::sleep_for(std::chrono::seconds(20));

// Safely kills all operations and resources before delete
io->close();

// A hack solution to allow time for the detached thread to do what it needs to do
//std::this_thread::sleep_for(std::chrono::milliseconds(1000));

// Crashes if I don't allow the detached thread to safely close
delete io;

return EXIT_SUCCESS;
```

Comment: Use some sort of condition variable and make `close` wait until all detached threads notify they are done.

Comment: @NathanOliver I should have put that in my original post but I am trying to avoid a condition variable, if possible. I was hoping for a more clean solution, like joining a detached thread. Though I understand that is not possible with the current spec.

Comment: Either provide your own synchronisation mechanism, or don't use `detach`.

Comment: Can I ask why the threads are detached in the first place?  Why not have an `std::thread m_thread` member of `io_socket` and have the `io_socket` destructor perform the necessary clean up?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming that the IO thread is coded by you, you can handle this with a combination of `std::promise` and `std::future`, something like this:

```
#include <chrono>
#include <thread>
#include <future>
#include <iostream>

using namespace std::chrono_literals;

void demo_thread (std::promise <bool> *p)
{
    std::cout << "demo thread waiting...\n";
    std::this_thread::sleep_for (1000ms);
    std::cout << "demo thread terminating\n";
    p->set_value (true);
}

int main ()
{
    std::promise <bool> p;
    std::thread t = std::thread (demo_thread, &p);
    t.detach ();

    // ...

    std::cout << "main thread waiting...\n";
    std::future <bool> f = p.get_future();
    f.wait ();

    std::cout << "main thread terminating\n";
}
```

[Live demo](https://wandbox.org/permlink/sXOP18977FsrPNAC)

Comment: This was the answer I was looking for. I don't have much experience with C++ futures but this looks like the direction I wanted to go. Thank you.

Answer (score 2):

You cannot reattach a `std::thread` that you have detached.  The only way to wait for a detach thread to end is to use some sort of atomic/condition variable to notify you when it it done.

That said, you probably don't need to detach the thread in the first place.  What you can do is create storage for the threads to live in (`std::vector<std::thread>` comes to mind) and then in `open` you add the new thread to that storage.  Once you are all done you call `close` and have `close` go through every thread in the storage and call `join` on it.  This will make `close` your synchronization point and after that you know that all threads have ended and you are safe to close the application.

Answer (score 1):

> Is it possible to rejoin the detached thread?

No. That would defeat the whole purpose of `detach()`.

A `t.detach()` call does not actually do anything essential. It's only purpose is to disable a safety mechanism.

Normally, if you don't `detach()` a thread, then the destructor for the `thread` object will throw an error if you allow the object to be destroyed before your program has `join()ed` it. The only purpose for that is to help you to avoid a common mistake: It's meant to prevent your `main()` routine from exiting and terminating the program before all of the other threads have finished.

The purpose of `t.detach()`---the *only* purpose---is to tell the library, "Thanks, but I know what I'm doing, I don't want the help, and I am *NEVER* going to call `t.join()`.

---

If you want your program to call `t.join()` then don't call `t.detach()`.

Answer (score 0):

NathanOliver has provided a good answer, but his solution may prove difficult if the `io->open()` function does not return a reference to the std::thread object it creates (which, if it detaches, it likely doesn't). If you are using the Asio library directly, I would expect that `io->close()` should be properly handling graceful exit of the thread before you delete `io`. However, if this is a wrapper you've implemented, you either need to return a reference to the created thread object in `open()`, or change your implementation of `close()` so that it blocks until the resources have actually been deallocated. Furthermore, if these are methods implemented yourself, is the detach in `open()` even necessary?